# Редирект с директории на вложенную директорию .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно написать редирект с
/product/sofa/ на /product/sofa/laguna/20111/
При классическом
Redirect 301 /product/sofa/ /product/sofa/laguna/20111/
ERR_TOO_REDIRECTS

Answer (score 0):

Вот так

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^product/sofa/$ /product/sofa/laguna/20111/? [R=301,L]
```

[Верификация корректности правила](https://htaccess.madewithlove.com?share=0e9abee3-bbd0-46f7-896c-9711cfc146a4)

Comment: не отработало, увы.

Comment: @Olga, можете убедиться в правильности https://htaccess.madewithlove.com?share=0e9abee3-bbd0-46f7-896c-9711cfc146a4. У вас там что-то мешает этому правилу. Или кеш удалите. Правило рабочее.

Comment: Да, в верификации все работает, а на сервере, увы, нет.
Может есть еще вариант?

Comment: Дело не в варианте. Скорее всего, у вас есть другие правила в .htaccess ( я уверен, у вас Apache), которые перебивают мое правило.  Огласите, как говорится, весь список, пожалуйста.